# What is MS Access ODBC SQL syntax for a table with AutoIncrement and Memo columns?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, identity, ms-access-2007

I am migrating a full framework .NET app to core. It used ADOX to create an MS Access database and  tables. It used OLE DB to populate data. In ADOX, the data type was `ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger` and the syntax from c# was:

```
fld.Properties["Autoincrement"].Value = true;
fld.Properties["Seed"].Value = 1;
fld.Properties["Increment"].Value = 1;
```

For `memo`, ADOX data type was `ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarWChar`.

Since we can no longer use ADOX under .NET Core, I have to use SQL DML through ODBC. When I attempt to create a table using syntax similar to

```
create table t (
  col1 int not null identity(1,1),
  col2 varchar(512)
)
```

I get a syntax error. When I try to adjust this for Access according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql) and other related articles in the same documentation tree, I also get syntax error.

```
create table t (
  col1 counter,
  col2 text
)
```

What is the correct syntax for these columns that is compatible with .NET Core and MS Access ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `adLongVarWChar` is a valid type in Access but you can use `MEMO` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [T](
    [col1] COUNTER,
    [col2] MEMO,
    CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY ([col1])
)
```

That final `CONSTRAINT` is critical to go from just an `AutoIncrement` to your primary key, which I assume is what you are trying to do.

The other format that Access likes looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [T] (
  [col1] AUTOINCREMENT CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  [col2] LONGTEXT
)
```

Let me know which one works for you.

Comment: Isn't `UNIQUE` redundant in the presence of `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: It absolutely should be. That is what came out when I exported the SQL for the table created by the first example. So it's what access does internally. They are identical.